# What is the difference between "tensorflow.math.multiply" and "tensorflow.keras.layers.multiply"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, layer, loss

What is the difference between `tensorflow.math.multiply` and `tensorflow.keras.layers.multiply`?

Similarly, 
What is the difference between `tensorflow.math.add` and `tensorflow.keras.layers.add`?

The reason why I have this question is that when I build my own customized loss function and metrics `product = multiply([y_true_f, y_pred_f])`, if I use `from tensorflow.keras.layers import multiply`, errors occured:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must
>   feed a value for placeholder tensor 'main_target' with dtype float and
>   shape [?,?,?]

But if I use `from tensorflow.math import multiply`, it works normally.

I want to know why. Thanks.
(I use tensorflow 1.15, ubuntu18)

**Update**:
After `import tensorflow.kera.backend as K`

**what is the difference between `tf.multiply` and `.*`?**

**Similarly, What is the difference between `K.pow` and `/`??**

I write the following codes of a customized metrics function based on some other's codes.

```
def dice_coef_weight_sub(y_true, y_pred):
    """
    Returns the product of dice coefficient for each class
    """
    y_true_f = (Lambda(lambda y_true: y_true[:, :, :, :, 0:])(y_true))
    y_pred_f = (Lambda(lambda y_pred: y_pred[:, :, :, :, 0:])(y_pred))

    product = tf.multiply([y_true_f, y_pred_f]) # multiply should be import from tf or tf.math

    red_y_true = K.sum(y_true_f, axis=[0, 1, 2, 3]) # shape [None, nb_class]
    red_y_pred = K.sum(y_pred_f, axis=[0, 1, 2, 3])
    red_product = K.sum(product, axis=[0, 1, 2, 3])

    smooth = 0.001
    dices = (2. * red_product + smooth) / (red_y_true + red_y_pred + smooth)

    ratio = red_y_true / (K.sum(red_y_true) + smooth)
    ratio = 1.0 - ratio
    # ratio =  K.pow(ratio + smooth, -1.0) # different method to get ratio

    return K.sum(multiply([dices, ratio]))
```

In the codes, can I replace `tf.multiply` by `.*`? Can I replace `K.pow` by `/`??

(From tensorflow's document, I know the difference between `tf.pow` and `K.pow`: `tf.pow(x,y)` receives 2 tensors to compute x^y for corresponding elements in `x` and `y`, while `K.pow(x,a)` receives a tensor `x` and a integer `a` to compute x^a. But I do not know why in the above code `K.pow` receives a float number 1.0 and it still works norally)

Answer (score 3):

All classes in `tensorflow.keras.layers` are Keras layers, meaning that they take as input Keras tensors produced by other layers (in the functional API), or they can be arranged to make sequential models using the Sequential API.

Other tensorflow functions like the ones in `tensorflow.math` are meant to operate in tensorflow (not keras) tensors. For a custom loss, the inputs and outputs are tensorflow tensors, so you should use tensorflow functions and not Keras layers.

Keras layer operations are used when you want to perform such operation as part of a neural network architecture, for example the `add` layer is used to implement residual connections in a ResNet architecture.

Comment: Dear Matias, I updated the question, could you please answer it again??

Comment: @jingnan, your question was answered. Just check Matia's answer as solution, upvote it if is a good answer for you, and write a new question instead to change this one.

Comment: @daniherrera OK， I upvoted it. And I post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59578808/what-is-the-difference-between-tf-multiply-and)

Comment: Good idea Jingan